# How to create subheaders from a vector in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

If I have a vector like so:

```
id_vector <- c("ID1", "ID5", "ID101")
```

How can I create a subheader for each item in the vector within a for loop?

Desired output:

```
ID1
   Test text
ID5
   Test text
ID101
   Test text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example R Markdown to try. You can use `cat` with varying the `#` for level of the subheading. You will need the `results = 'asis'` option in your chunk. Make sure to add newline `\n` before and after headings.

````
---
title: "Subheaders from vector"
output: html_document
---

# Main Header 1

```{r, echo = FALSE}
id_vector <- c("ID1", "ID5", "ID101")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
for (i in seq_along(id_vector)) {
  cat("\n### ", id_vector[i], "\n")
  cat("Test text\n")
}
```
````